# PHP's cUrl function returning bad characters

Tags: php, encoding, curl

I'm attempting to retrieve a remote HTML page with cURL - however, when I analyze the text that gets returned, I'm noticing alot of odd characters like `Ã¢Â–Â€Ã`, which makes me think that something went wrong with the text encoding somewhere along the line.

How can I ensure that the text I get back from cURL is properly encoded, and how can I normalize it so I can safely store results in a database without any encoding issues?

Comment: Is the page you are retrieving UTF-8 or Latin1?

Answer (score 5):

I hope you have set CURLOPT_ENCODING to "" and the page is not full of those gibberish which you see, second thing I can suggest is to run the string through some thing like html entities to sanitise it. Curl simply gets/posts the data and, IMHO, doesn't change the encodings

Answer (score -1):

You need to include the following on the top of your page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Right, because changing the doctype helps with encoding issues... -1